# Is it possible to update a QProgressDialog with concurrent futures ProcessPoolExecutor with PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, multiprocessing, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a GUI for some of my Python scripts at work using PyQt5.

I'm interested in running a series of tasks on separate processes (not threads).  I've been using the concurrent futures ProcessPoolExecutor to execute the jobs. I've tried using the iterators from concurrent.futures.as_completed() to update the value in my QProgressBar.

```
def join(self):
    for fut in concurrent.futures.as_completed(self._tasks):

        try:            
            self.results.put(fut.result())
            self.dialogBox.setValue(self.results.qsize())

        except concurrent.futures.CancelledError:
            break
```

However, it seems like my method seems to block the gui even though the work is running on another processes.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: ... "blocking/locking" that sounds like your threading instead of using multiprocessing, which means there is a process waiting to be finished..but never happens...but hey... without code it could be "I'm riding my broomstick or flying carpet" instead of a bike.